# ¿Cómo hago para modificar algún html con jquery? ...pues con el append crea un nuevo html, no lo reemplaza

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, dom

¿Cómo hago para modificar algún html con jquery? Porque con el append me crea un nuevo html, no lo reemplaza. Yo tengo mi código así:

```
document.getElementById("precioTotal").innerHTML=`<h4><b>El precio total de sus productos seleccionados es de: $${montoTotal}</b></h4>
```

De esa manera yo reemplazo lo que tenía antes. (Lo hago para ir modificando el precio total del carrito a medida que el usuario elige nuevos productos). Pero si quiero seleccionarlo con JQUERY (en vez de "document.getElementById" usaría $("#precioTotal").append (lo hago con append pero me agrega html sobre el que ya está y yo lo que quiero es reemplazarlo/setearlo).

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de "append" usa "html":

```
$("#precioTotal").html(`<h4><b>El precio total de sus productos seleccionados es de: ${montoTotal}</b></h4>`);
```

Cuando.html() se usa para darle contenido a un elemento HTML, cualquier contenido que estuviera en el elemento es reemplazado por el nuevo contenido. - [API JQuery .html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)